# Partition a number into three parts, and make lcm(a,b,c) as small as possible

Tags: algorithm, math

> Suppose `n` be an integer `> 2`. How do we find `3` positive integers `a, b, c,` such that `n = a+b+c` and that their least common multiple, `lcm(a,b,c)`, are as small as possible?
>
> For example, `17 = 2+5+10` and `lcm(2,5,10) = 10`. However, `17=(1+8+8)` and `lcm(1,8,8)=8` also is possible. Thus, in this problem, the division of `17` into `1,8,8` is better than `2,5,10`.
>
> `2 < n < 2^31`

I have no idea about it, because the number might go up to `2^31`.

I already know if `n%3=0` then `a=b=c=n/3`, but I don't know how to do it when `n%3!=0`.

Comment: I proved my conjecture from last night.

Answer (score 5):

Assume without loss of generality that a ≥ b ≥ c. By an averaging argument, a ≥ n/3. If lcm(a, b, c) < 2n/3, then since a divides lcm(a, b, c), we must have lcm(a, b, c) = a, and b and c divide a.

If n is a power of two, then the optimal solution is n/2, n/4, n/4. Proof: the quoted solution is valid, so lcm(a, b, c) ≤ n/2. Since n/2 < 2n/3, it follows that b and c divide a ≤ n/2. Accordingly, a must be even, and b and c must be both odd or both even. If b and c are both odd, then a/2 ≥ b ≥ c, and so a + b + c = n only if b = c = a/2 = n/4.  If b and c are both even, then we divide everything by 2 and argue by induction.

If n is not a power of two, then let its least odd prime divisor be p (find p using Pollard's rho or maybe sieving primes up to √2<sup>31</sup> and trial division); the optimal solution is (n/p) (p−1)/2, (n/p) (p−1)/2, n/p. Proof: the quoted solution is valid, so lcm(a, b, c) ≤ (n/p) (p−1)/2. Since (n/p) (p−1)/2 < 2n/3, it follows that b and c divide a ≤ (n/p) (p−1)/2. We must have b = a, or else a/2 ≥ b ≥ c would imply that n ≤ 2a ≤ 2 (n/p) (p−1)/2 = n (1 − 1/p), which is false. Accordingly, the solution has the form (n − c)/2, (n − c)/2, c. The optimal solution takes c to be the largest proper divisor of n having the same parity as n, which is c = n/p.

Comment: Very nice, just a couple of things: (1) In the sentence beginning "We must have b = a" in para 3, how do you get "2a = 2 (n/p) (p−1)/2"? It looks to me like that is just a conclusion about the quoted solution's a, not a necessary fact for all possible a. (2) In a couple of places in para 3 you have written "(n/p) (n−1)/2" where I think you meant "(n/p) (p−1)/2".

Comment: @j_random_hacker (1) Ah, we only have inequality there, but that's OK. That's from the fact that lcm(a, b, c) = a and the assumption that a, b, c are at least as good as the quoted solution. (2) Fixed.